# Invoking WCF functions using Reflection

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection

I have a WCF application that is using `NetTcpBinding`. I want to invoke the functions in WCF service using `Methodbase.Invoke` from the `System.Reflection` namespace. In other words I want to Dynamically call a Function by passing a `String` as the Function name.

Reflection works great for Web Service or a Windows application or any DLL or class. So there is certainly a way to do this for WCF but I am unable to find out how.

I am getting the Assembly Name then it's type everything fine but as we cannot create an instance of the Interface class. I tried to open the WCF connection using the binding and tried to pass that object but it's throwing an exception as:

"Object does not match target type."

I have opened the connection and passed the object and type is of interface only. I don't know whether I'm trying the wrong thing or am using the wrong way. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

The `NetTCPBinding` all are properly given while opening the connection. I am using WCF as a Windows Service using `NETTCPBinding`.

Comment: How do you get hold of the proxy ?

Comment: I have added the Interface class in my application so I'm using that interface class to create the channel.

Comment: Show code and configuration please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the correct instance when you invoke your method.  This instance is the proxy object created via the interface-based call to ChannelFactory.  I tried your technique on a hello world style application and got the expected results. One thing I don't see in your code example is how you initialize the parameters.  That could be a problem.  I believe think that your call to Type.GetType may be causing the error you are receiving. Notice I call GetType on the Proxy object.  I include my sample code below that calls a Function GetData that takes one argument as an integer.
...

```
 Dim myFactory As ChannelFactory(Of SimpleService.IService1)
    myFactory = New ChannelFactory(Of SimpleService.IService1)(myBinding, myEndpoint)
    oProxy = myFactory.CreateChannel()
    'commented out version that does same call without reflection
    ' oProxy.GetData(3)
   Dim oType As Type = oProxy.GetType
   Dim oMeth As MethodInfo = oType.GetMethod("GetData")
   Dim params() As Object = {3}
   Dim sResults As String
   sResults = oMeth.Invoke(oProxy, BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, params, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Comment: Hey it worked!!! It was a silly mistake. I was again casting my type for the fully qualified interface instead of proxy. After pointing to my proxy it;s working now. Thanks alot.