# How can I Invoke WCF Service using reflection ?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have WCF service end points; I do not have access to its interface (i.e. Contract) of that service. I have its EndPoint details and MethodName which I need to invoke.

How can I do this in C#; I am using netTcpBinding...

Thanks in advance

Ocean

Comment: Are you trying to connect to arbitrary services, or a single known service?

Comment: If you have the assembly, you can simply reference the assembly and instantiate the types you're talking about--no need for reflection.  Please explain why you can't do that so someone can offer some advice.

Comment: There's an answer here that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470195/invoking-wcf-functions-using-reflection

Comment: I would not know about the service before hand; I will not have access to assembly so I can not instantiate. And yes it would be arbitrary service. And also I do not have access to contract as well...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can use the WsdlImporter to contact the WSDL and grab the metadata (like the DataContracts and the OperationContracts).  For example:

```
        MetadataExchangeClientMode mexMode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet;

        // Get Metadata file from service
        MetadataExchangeClient mexClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(mexAddress, mexMode);
        mexClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
        MetadataSet metaSet = mexClient.GetMetadata(mexAddress, mexMode);

        //Import all contracts and endpoints
        WsdlImporter importer = new WsdlImporter(metaSet);
        var contracts = importer.ImportAllContracts();
        ServiceEndpointCollection allEndpoints = importer.ImportAllEndpoints();

        //Generate type information for each contract
        ServiceContractGenerator generator = new ServiceContractGenerator();
        this.EndpointsForContracts = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint>>();

        foreach (ContractDescription contract in contracts)
        {
            generator.GenerateServiceContractType(contract);
            // Inspect if the name matches one you're looking for, or do whatever
            //  else you might need
        }
```

Then you can dynamically compile the code into memory:

```
// Generate a code file for the contracts 
        CodeGeneratorOptions options = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
        options.BracingStyle = "C";
        CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");

        // Compile the code file to an in-memory assembly
        // Don't forget to add all WCF-related assemblies as references
        CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(
            new string[] { 
                "System.dll", "System.ServiceModel.dll", 
                "System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" });
        compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

        CompilerResults results = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(compilerParameters, generator.TargetCompileUnit);
```

Finally, you can execute the methods accordingly:

```
Type clientProxyType = this.Cr.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.IsClass && t.GetInterface(listServiceContracts.SelectedValue) != null && t.GetInterface(typeof(ICommunicationObject).Name) != null);
object dataContract = this.Cr.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(dataContractType.FullName, false, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null);

// set the dataContract properties however they need to be set

// Get the first service endpoint for the contract
        ServiceEndpoint serviceEndPoint = this.EndpointsForContracts[listServiceContracts.SelectedValue].First();

        object clientProxyInstance = this.Cr.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(clientProxyType.Name, false, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, new object[] { serviceEndPoint.Binding, serviceEndPoint.Address }, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null);

        Type myType = clientProxyInstance.GetType();
        object[] arg = { dataContract };

        // Now call the remote procedure via SOAP, get back response
        var returnVal = myType.InvokeMember("OPERATION YOU WANT TO EXECUTE", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, clientProxyInstance, arg);
```

Again, this may not be perfect for what you're looking to do, and your post was so long ago that this may be old news.  But just in case... hopefully this is helpful.  You will likely need to inspect the Types that get returned in order to determine how to set the DataContract argument properly.  Also, the above assumes that the method you're calling only takes in one argument, the DataContract object.

Hope this gets you on the right track, if you still need it.